# How to programmatically update a contact's embedded data in Qualtrics

Tags: qualtrics

I have an embedded data field on each of my contacts. It is a list of companies. I would like to know if I can update this field after the contact has completed the survey? The idea is that the person will complete the survey multiple times over several weeks, and on each time I want the embedded data field to update based on the user's response to the previous surveys. The reason for this is simple, I want the survey to change based on the individual's previous responses.

I've looked at Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData() and this does save the embedded data to the survey results, but I need a way to save that data to each contact.

The only way I see is to manually export results after each survey, then copy those into a .csv contacts file, then upload the .csv to update the embedded data field.

Is there a more automatic way to do this, with javascript for example?

Answer (score 0):

Use Tools/Triggers/Contact List Triggers.